# Passing 1D arrays as elements of a 3D array in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow: I have a set of arrays, x0,x1,x2 and x3 that are generated in my program and each array has N elements. I also have a zeros-initialized 3D tensor of dimensions (N,2,2).

I want to make each of the array as the element of my 3D tensor (with the N elements in the third direction), M[:,0,0] =x0, M[:,0,1] =x1, M[:,1,0] =x2 and M[:,1,1] =x3, and I want to do that with for loops.

In Matlab which I am more familiar with it is possible to do that by simply:

```
M(1,1,:)=x0
M(2,2,:)=x3
M(1,2,:)=x1
M(2,1,:)=x2
```

Is there a way that I can pass arrays in a for loop as the third dimension of my tensor in tensor flow, for example:

```
for i in range(2):
    M[:,i,i]=x
```

where x is an array?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would work that way. You could do:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x0,x1,x2,x3 = [ np.random.randint(0,10,3) for _ in range(4)]
tf_X = tf.stack( [ tf.stack([x0,x1]),
                   tf.stack([x2,x3]) ])
```

EDIT: It might change with `Tensorflow2` though. Otherwise,  you could use `pytorch`:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

X = torch.ones([3,4])
v = np.arange(4)

X[0,:] = torch.from_numpy(v)
```

Result:

```
In [20]: X
Out[20]:
tensor([[0., 1., 2., 3.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Comment: Hello @Nakor: so just to be clear, is there a way to replace the elements of a 3D tensor by inserting a full array in the third dimension. Say I have a zeros-initialized 3D tensor of size (10,2,2) and I want to insert  an array at the location M[:,1,1]=x to replace the zeros. Is that not possible ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: However, I did not try with Tensorflow 2.0, it might very change since their API is way more numpy like. If you don't mid changing API, you might also consider using pytorch (see my edits)

Comment: Hello @Nakor:  I just realized that there is a way to do that in tensorflow. You need to initialize M as a variable tensor, then you can use M[:,i,j].assign(x), where x is the array that you place in the third dimension of the tensor

Comment: Oh interesting. So do you do that inside a session I guess?